# "Frequency" shift in discrete FFT in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft

*(Disclaimer: I thought about posting this on math.statsexchange, but found similar questions there that were moved to SO, so here I am)*

The context:

I'm using fft/ifft to determine probability distributions for sums of random variables.
So e.g. I'm having two uniform probability distributions - in the simplest case two uniform distributions on the interval [0,1].

So to get the probability distribution for the sum of two random variables sampled from these two distributions, one can calculate the product of the fourier-transformed of each probabilty density.
Doing the inverse fft on this product, you get back the probability density for the sum.

An example:

```
function usumdist_example()

    x = linspace(-1, 2, 1e5);
    dx = diff(x(1:2));
    NFFT = 2^nextpow2(numel(x));

    % take two uniform distributions on [0,0.5]
    intervals = [0, 0.5;
                 0, 0.5];
    figure();
    hold all;
    for i=1:size(intervals,1)
        % construct the prob. dens. function
        P_x = x >= intervals(i,1) & x <= intervals(i,2);
        plot(x, P_x);

        % for each pdf, get the characteristic function fft(pdf,NFFT)
        % and form the product of all char. functions in Y
        if i==1
            Y = fft(P_x,NFFT) / NFFT;
        else
            Y = Y .* fft(P_x,NFFT) / NFFT;
        end
    end
    y = ifft(Y, NFFT);

    x_plot = x(1) + (0:dx:(NFFT-1)*dx);
    plot(x_plot, y / max(y), '.');

end
```

My issue is, the shape of the resulting prob. dens. function is perfect.
However, the x-axis does not fit to the `x` I create in the beginning, but is shifted.
In the example, the peak is at 1.5, while it should be 0.5.

The shift changes if I e.g. add a third random variable or if I modify the range of `x`.
But I can't get figure how.

I'm afraid it might have to do with the fact that I'm having negative `x` values, while fourier transforms usually work in a time/frequency domain, where `frequencies < 0` don't make sense.

I'm aware I could find e.g. the peak and shift it to its proper place, but seems nasty and error prone...

Glad about any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your x origin is -1, not 0. You expect the center of the triangular pdf to be at .5, because that's twice the value of the center of the uniform pdf. However, the correct reasoning is: the center of the uniform pdf is 1.25 above your minimum x, and you get the center of the triangle at 2*1.25 = 2.5 above the minimum x (that is, at 1.5).

In other words: although your original x axis is (-1, 2), the convolution (or the FFT) behave as if it were (0, 3). In fact, the FFT knows nothing about your x axis; it only uses the y samples. Since your uniform is zero for the first samples, that zero interval of width 1 is amplified to twice its width when you do the convolution (or the FFT). I suggest drawing the convolution on paper to see this (draw original signal, reflected signal about y axis, displace the latter and see when both begin to overlap). So you need a correction in the `x_plot` line to compensate for this increased width of the zero interval: use

```
x_plot = 2*x(1) + (0:dx:(NFFT-1)*dx);
```

and then `plot(x_plot, y / max(y), '.')` will give the correct graph:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Since the application should be more general - does the  `2` really simply connect to the number of convolutions, hence pdfs in my case? At first it seems so, but just to be sure...  Barely having worked with convolution I don't really get the background yet, should try to read that up somewhere. And yes, I was  aware that fft doesn't know my `x` values. The issue is rather, that the pdf's don't start at the first input?!

Comment: @sebastian Yes. For 3 variables you would use `x_plot = 3*x(1) + (0:dx:(NFFT-1)*dx)` etc. But: be sure to increase your x axis upper limit_, for example `x = linspace(-1, 4, 1e5);`. The reason is that the convolved pdf gets wider as you increase the number of random variables. This, combined with the fact that the FFT is a _circular_ convolution (i.e. assumes your signals are periodic), might give strange results (a sort of time-domain aliasing). For example, with 3 variables you'll see `x = linspace(-1, 2, 1e5)` gives wrong results. Increase to `linspace(-1, 4, 1e5)` and you will get it right

Comment: Yes I noticed that - the signal gets wrapped around. Realizing the product of fft's is "just" the convolution, maybe that would have been the easier approach :> Though it seems to be significantly slower...